# Could Not Connect strophe js connection after DISCONNECTED status

Tags: javascript, xmpp, chat, strophe

Currently I have integrating **strophe** in my chat application.Its working fine until user is online
But, when i try to **switch the another wifi connection** in my system, strophe sends the **DISCONNECTED**
I don't have any idea to make it to reconnect automatically in such situation. Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using BOSH to connect to your server then you can add keepalive to your connection string

```
new Strophe.Connection(this._xmppConnectionsString, { 'keepalive': true })
```

If you are using Web Sockets to connect then you need to write a setInterval after the initial connection success.

```
    setInterval(function(){ 
                    this._xmppConnection.send($pres().tree()); 
                }, 12000);
```

This should solve your problem.